# How to loop through weeks in different year

Tags: php

I have input as `$fromweek=50` and `$fromyear=2015`
then `$toweek=2` and `$toyear=2016`

How do I loop week number in a table column ?

```
for ($i=$fromweek; $i<=$toweek; $i++) {            
    echo '<th>week '.$i.'</th>';
}
```

Comment: Normalise to timestamp, then use `str_to_date` to do `+1 week` until you are at the end.

Comment: what you need from these?? just `51, 52, 1` as week number?

Comment: yes i need 50, 51, 52, 1, 2 like

Comment: 2015 was a [53 week year](http://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2015).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be careful here as according to the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) standard some years can have 53 weeks. Your example year, [2015 is one of these](http://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2015).

The [\DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) classes are the way to do this. They will automatically account for leapyears etc and make date manipulation much easier. It is worth taking the time to read up on them.

Something like this should work for you:

```
$fromweek=50;
$fromyear=2015;
$toweek=2;
$toyear=2016;
$interval = new DateInterval('P7D');

$start = (new \DateTime())->setISODate($fromyear, $fromweek);
$end = (new \DateTime())->setISODate($toyear, $toweek);

$period = new \DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end->add($interval));

foreach($period as $date){
    echo $date->format('d-m-Y') .  PHP_EOL;
}
```

[See it working](https://3v4l.org/N0IPI).

Answer (score 2):

You could create two dates using week number and year, and compare them (while `$date1` exceeds `$date2`), and increase `$date1` by week using `DateInterval`, see example below:

```
$date1 = new DateTime();
$date1->setISODate(2015, 50);

$date2 = new DateTime();
$date2->setISODate(2016, 2);

while($date1 <= $date2) {
    echo $date1->format('W').PHP_EOL;
    $date1->add(new DateInterval('P1W'));
}
```

In Action: https://eval.in/573305

Comment: That's a nice solution keeping the while loop.